Geo Nodes - Deform Object to Curve
I have found the setup to imitate the curve modifier with geometry nodes. And sofar it works great. I have however one problem. The curve modifier keeps "looping" the object around the curve, while the geo nodes setup stops at the beginning/end of the curve.

I have currently no idea how I can work around that in the geo nodes setup. Here is the node setup. 
I appreciate any help/ideas in which direction to go.


Normal · Tangent will always yield zero. You want cross product there instead to produce a 3rd axis. Other than that you want you want to use wrapping (Math node: Wrap or modulo) to wrap the negative x into positive length.

The Wrap mode never caught my eye, I will definetly remember it in the future, thank you for this useful tip!

(Using Blender 4.2.0)
The length of the object to wrap is greater than the length of the curve, and its X coordinate does not start at 0. Consequently, the object is truncated. One approach is to sample the curve by Factor instead of Length. The X coordinate of the object to wrap is normalized between 0 and 1 using a Map Range node. Bounds of X are recovered from an Attribute Statics node.

Resources:
(Blender 4.2.0+)

Side note: to keep the aspect ratio of the object to wrap, its Z coordinate should be scaled by the length of the curve divided by the length of the object to wrap.

This is it! Thank you!!!
How did you hid the unconnected outputs of the Separate XYZ node :)?

To hide unconnected sockets, use ctrl+h after selecting a node.

Thank you guys!!!
I added a wrap math node as suggested by Markus von Broadly to the setup from StefLancien and achieved the wanted result.
Now I can continue wrapping the geometry around the curve beyond the 1 range.

